Black & white, maybe French movie with small sail boat important to plot and maybe title
Extremely vague details:

B&W
Murder took place (PROBABLY)
Sailing boat wandered through river canals and some swamp like water areas
Title maybe had something to do with cutting knife as a reference to the trail that the boat leaves on very still water
At a certain point, one guy leaves the boat and pushes it through very shallow water.
Could be french or American can't remember.
Decade guess: 50's?

Good luck to the winner, if you solve it, you're not only a movie genius, but also you have solved a mystery that's been accompanying me for more than 15 years, which was when I saw it.

It all sounds like Roman Polanski's Knife in the Water from 1962.

While driving to sail with his wife Krystyna in his yacht, the arrogant and wealthy Andrzej "stumbles" with a drifter in front of his car hitchhiking on the lonely road. Andrzej gives a ride to the young man with despisal. When they reach the marina, Andrzej unexpectedly and without any reason invites the young man to sail with them, initiating a tense dispute of power with the youth, in a claustrophobic and erotic environment. 

It's in black and white, a sailboat is integral, and, well, the title. It's in Polish, though (it was nominated for an Oscar for Best Foreign Film). Here's a scene from the film:




Lol that was quick. Yup this is the one, last time I tried to google it, I couldn't remember the title reference. Polish, who would figure? Thank you so much, can't wait to watch it again.

@jjdns No problem. Don't forget to click on the check mark to approve this and resolve the question.
